# Selenium java I want to run test scripts on multiple browsers, versions so what is best approach

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

At present I have a framework which support firefox browser only. Now I am going to enhance my frame work so that can any give your ideas to me by suggesting your thoughts.

At present I am using Selenium Java, Hybrid framework, maven setup, Webdriver surefire reports.
So

1) If I want to run test cases on multiple browsers and multiple version of browsers parallel. what is the best approach?

Thanks
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to setup the [grid](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) for parallel runs.

You need to make your browser launch code depend on a configurable parameter.
You can either take it as a parameter of the testng xml or make it as a system argument.
Depending on the value of this parameter, your listeners or your launch code (I am hoping that would be isolated since u mention a framework is in place) should be able to use this parameter to make a decision on what browser/node to launch.

For parallel runs, it would be better if you can use some framework.  We use testng as the framework which supports parallel runs with good results.

Comment: Thanks Niharika for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I know you dont want to hear it, but best way actually is *trial and error*

- Your site is going to behave differently in different browsers. So you will have to update your script for *almost every browser* and you will have to do it **manually**
- Browsing speed is going to be different. Maybe invest in Implicit wait into your script
- And yes, you are going to hate it.

My "best approach" is:

1. Implement the script for one most used browser and automate as much as possible
2. In other versions do manual shakedown of most crucial functions
3. Communicate with business to write somewhere that some obscure browsers (like IE 6) are no longer supported so you have more time to polish the script

Comment: Well, I beg to differ about the "hate" part and "update the script for every browser". I have been doing this for last 3 years using selenium. Yes, I had to occasionally but never "almost every browser". If we have to update the code for every browser then it means we loose one of the biggest advantage of using Selenium - one code all browsers. If your site behaves differently in each browser, then its a problem with your application. Shouldn't a website behave the same way in all browsers?